# Translate the page numbers of internal links in a pdf link to?

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I use pdftk to (extract and) merge some pdf files. One of the input pdf files has internal links within it, i.e. when clicking such links will jump to another position in the pdf file. But in the output pdf file, the page numbers that the internal links link do not change, so they link to the wrong pages.

The best thing I know is that all internal links link to the wrong pages away from the connect pages by a fixed number of pages.

e.g. `pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf cat output merge.pdf` where `2.pdf` has internal links.

e.g. `pdftk A=1.pdf B=2.pdf cat A1-10 B1-4 A11-20 B5-end   output merge.pdf` 
where I want to translate the internal links from page 5 till end in `2.pdf`

How shall I update the internal links? Thanks.

Comment: Only an idea: http://www.sejda.org/  Thus the merge should also work with bookmarks.

Comment: internal links aren't bookmarks aka outlines. internal links are in the main text, while bookmarks are not (but shown in side panel of evince)